# Spotify App -- App keep getting unloaded

Tags: javascript, api, spotify

I am trying to build an app for Spotify using the new Spotify API (v1.0.0). But I'm having trouble as my app doesn't refresh after a period of tim. It's like it is getting disconnected from the Spotify API.

I build a minimal app to better explain the situation. You can find the main javascript file [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6363382#file-main-js), along with the other necessary files for an app.

This minimal app does just one simple thing: it outputs the names of song played to the console. So if you start the app and listen to 5 songs, you should have the name of the five songs appear in the console. Instead, the app sometimes disconnects and doesn't catch song until you go back to the app and manually refresh it.

How to reproduce the issue?

- load the minimal app (using `spotify:app:spotify-test-app`), and click Add to keep the app alive
- see that it works well by going the console, the name of the current playing song should appear
- go to another app, or just browse some music
- wait ~10 minutes
- go back to `spotify:app:spotify-test-app`
- go to the console
- the song list is only made of the currently playing track, because the app *disconnected* and during some time has not updated the track name list in the console

I reproduced this issue on several Mac OS X laptops.

Is anybody else having this issue? Any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an intentional feature of the Apps API — apps that aren't actively controlling playback are suspended when they haven't been active for a little while for performance reasons.